# Error Help::Multiple controls with the same ID 'ctl00' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net

Getting the above Error.
I want the IDs of the Accordian to be unique everytime it is bound. I added Accordian pane dynamically in my code..Its not working:-

like this :-

```
for(int i=0;i< dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{      

AccordionPane accp = new AccordionPane();
accp.ID = "accp" + i.ToString();
Accordion1.Panes.Add(accp);
Accordion1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
Accordion1.DataBind();
}
```

I want the IDs of the Accordian to be unique. How can I accomplish what I want ?

Aspx Page:-

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" OnTabClick="RadTabStrip1_OnTabClick" ClickSelectedTab="true">
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
<br /><br />
       <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0">

       </telerik:RadMultiPage>

    </div>

          <cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" FadeTransitions="true"  Visible="true" AutoSize="None"
                SelectedIndex="0" RequireOpenedPane="false"  TransitionDuration="250" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" ContentCssClass="accordionContent" CssClass="toggler">
                <HeaderTemplate>

                    <b style="color: Black">

                        <%#Eval("Ques")%>
                    </b>

                </HeaderTemplate>


                <ContentTemplate>
                <p> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuesAns")%></p>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:Accordion>
            <br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `BindAccordion` multiple times because (I'm guessing) that's why you're ending up with multiple controls with the same ID.

You're calling it in both `Page_Load` and `RadTabStrip1_OnTabClick`. My best guess from your code is that you should only call it once from `Page_Load` when `!IsPostBack` like you have already.

If that doesn't work, try the following:

```
protected void BindTabStrip()
{
    DataSet ds = GetDataSetForTabs();
    RadTabStrip1.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    RadTabStrip1.DataSource = ds;
    RadTabStrip1.DataTextField = "QuesType";
    RadTabStrip1.DataValueField = "QuesTypeID";
    RadTabStrip1.DataBind();

    // Remove it accordian from the page before adding it to 
    // a new ControlCollection
    Page.Controls.Remove(Accordian1); 

    RadPageView pv = new RadPageView();
    pv.Controls.Add(Accordion1);

    RadMultiPage1.PageViews.Add(pv);
}
```

Comment: If I dont call BindAccordian in OnTabClick method then when I click the tabs, no accordian is rendered on the page. I tried ur code..not working. How do I generate Unique ID for accordian every time a tab is clicked??

Comment: @Serenity - This all looks like a code smell to me anyway, but that's your prerogative. Anyway, this is nasty, but you could just do this: `accp.ID = "accp" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();`. If that doesn't fix it then the problem is somewhere else. If it does fix it, then it's not an ideal solution by a long shot.